# No Title Bar Showing in WPF .net 4.5 MahApps.Metro MvvmCross Composite Application

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross, mahapps.metro

Using MahApps Metro 1.1.2.0 in a .net 4.5 WPF MvvmCross (HotTuna 3.5.0) composite application, developing and running on Windows 7.

Have followed the quick start guide but when I run the app I see no title bar on the window.

The resources are added to the host application and I am not seeing

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warnings, e.g. 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='IdealForegroundColorBrush'
```

I have manually added the following properties to MainWindow.xaml but still no joy.

```
ResizeMode="CanResize"
ShowCloseButton="True"
ShowIconOnTitleBar="True"
ShowInTaskbar="True"
ShowMaxRestoreButton="True"
ShowMinButton="True"
ShowSystemMenuOnRightClick="True"
ShowTitleBar="True"
```

I added padding before the first control and made the background transparent on the mvx user control which is loaded into mainwindow by the view presenter to ensure it was not sitting on top of the menu, but all I see is a black background from the top of the window until the content begins.

Interestingly, adding a GlowBrush to main window does have an effect:

```
GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
```

Any help welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full MainWindow opening XAML tag?